# Combining indexed paragraphs into one large paragraph?

Tags: r, rvest

Is there a way to combine the output of this (in 12 sections) so that it is 1 large paragraph?

```
library(rvest)

story <- read_html(url("http://hamilton.edu/news/story/the-medias-effect-on-womens-body-image")) %>%
  html_nodes("#storyBody > p") %>%
  html_text

story
```

Output:

```
 [1] "While women have made significant strides in the past decades, the 
culture at large continues to place a great emphasis on how women look. 
These beauty standards, largely proliferated through the media, have drastic 
impacts on young women and their body images. Arielle Cutler ’11, through a 
Levitt grant, spent the summer evaluating the efficacy of media literacy 
programs as a remedy to this vicious cycle."                                                                                                                                                            

 [2] "Put simply, the beauty ideal in American culture is: thin. “Large 
populations of ‘average’ girls do not demonstrate clinically diagnosable 
eating disorders—pathologies that the culture marks as extreme and unhealthy
—but rather an entirely normative obsession with body shape and size,” 
Cutler said. “This ongoing concern is accepted as a completely normal and 
even inevitable part of being a modern girl. I think we need to change 
that.”" 

... 


[12] "Cutler is reading studies about the body image problem among women in 
the U.S. as well as evaluations of media literacy programs. She recommends 
greater sensitivity to the concerns of non-white, non-upper-class groups in 
order to increase the effectiveness of media literacy programs."
```

I'd ultimately like to get the output in one paragraph without spacing.

I can use glue(), but my code is inefficient, and I'm trying to find something that I can ultimately use to do multiple stories in a function.

```
library(glue)

glue(story[1], story[2], story[3], story[4], story[5], story[6], story[7], story[8], story[9], story[10], story[11], story[12])
```

My ideal output looks like this:

```
    While women have made significant strides in the past decades, the 
culture at large continues to place a great emphasis on how women look. 
These beauty standards, largely proliferated through the media, have drastic 
impacts on young women and their body images. Arielle Cutler ’11, through a 
Levitt grant, spent the summer evaluating the efficacy of media literacy 
programs as a remedy to this vicious cycle.Put simply, the beauty ideal in 
American culture is: thin. “Large populations of ‘average’ girls do not 
demonstrate clinically diagnosable eating disorders—pathologies that the 
culture marks as extreme and unhealthy—but rather an entirely normative 
obsession with body shape and size,” Cutler said. “This ongoing concern is 
accepted as a completely normal and even inevitable part of being a modern 
girl. I think we need to change that.”Anyone who is familiar with American 
culture knows that many of these cultural standards are established in the 
media. “We are constantly surrounded by all... <truncated>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what about `paste(story, collapse = " ")`?

Comment: Goddamn, such a simple solution -- knocking myself over the head for not thinking of that. Thanks, Kevin.

Also, it seems to work piped in as `%>% paste(collapse = " ")`

Comment: @EvanO. It may be worthwhile to answer your own question in detail and mark it as accepted.  Helps document questions with accepted answers.